# ¿Hay manera de cortar listas de palabras compuestas?

Tags: ortografía, estilo

El español no es el idioma más sintético, pero tiene sus palabras compuestas. Hace que existan familias de palabras con estructura bastante similar, por ejemplo:

> Hay anglohablantes, francohablantes e hispanohablantes aquí.

¿Es posible omitir la repetición en esta clase de frases? Algo como:

> Hay anglo-, franco- e hispanohablantes aquí.

Si es posible, ¿suena natural?

Comment: Suena perfectamente bien. La duda me entra en la ortografía, pero casi siempre lo veo sin guion. Luego si nadie ha enlazado a la Ortografía lo intentaré buscar

Answer (score 5):

He visto esto muchas veces.

En cuanto al guion: en inglés depende si el texto queda claro sin guion.

> Prefixes (such as de-, pre-, re-, and non-[10]) and suffixes (such as -less, -like, -ness, and -hood) may or may not be hyphenated. (The unhyphenated style is also called closed up or solid.) A rule of thumb is that they are not hyphenated unless the lack of a hyphen hurts clarity—specifically, clarity at first glance rather than clarity upon a second look or a moment's pause. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Prefixes_and_suffixes))

No encuentro nada parecido para el español, desgraciadamente.  De hecho encontré lo contrario:

> Cuando se desea unir en coordinación dos prefijos asociados a una misma palabra base, el primero de ellos se escribe de forma independiente y con guion, para evidenciar su condición de forma prefija y evitar, al mismo tiempo, la repetición de la base: Se harán descuentos en casos de pre- o recontratación de servicios.  ([RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=guion&origen=REDPD))

Answer (score -1):

En un texto formal yo no lo usaría ya que es preferible usar palabras largas y con repetición para no caer en un posible error aunque para acortar y de modo informal yo no tendría problema en usarlo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. De modo informal y en el lenguaje hablado creo que estaría bien. En escritos formales escribiría todo completo y sin los guiones.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo.  En un escrito formal, generalmente podemos confiar en que el lector será suficientemente sofisticado para entender la omisión.

Comment: Igual en contra. Basta con una lista de 3 palabras de este tipo escritas explícitamente para que el texto resulte cacofónico.

Comment: gracias @hlecuanda, la cacofonia es algo que tanto en la formalidad como en la informalidad es algo que se busca evitar al escribir y hablar